# building linux with openembedded

Tags: openembedded

I'am working on a project to build a Linux distribution with openembedded for the ARM, so I get bitbake and openembedded files and I set the variables `BBPATH` to bb files and path to bitbake and I run this command:

```
bitbake openembedded/recipes/linux/linux_2.6.39.bb
```

but i have this error and i can't fix it

```
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing
/home/otmane/Desktop/linux_oe/openembedded/recipes/linux/linux_2.6.39.bb:
Failure expanding expression ${@patch_deps(d)} which triggered
exception AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

I want to add that I'm working on an Ubuntu 14.04 host system in a VMWare workstation.

Comment: Exactly what have you downloaded? If it's openembedded, you really should be using openembedded-core instead. Could you give us the names and versions of your downloads?

Comment: i just run this command from ubuntu terminal : git clone git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded so i don't know if it's the oe-classic or oe-core

Comment: Then it is oe-classic. Please, use oe-core instead.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've downloaded "oe-classic", the old and unmaintained OE.  Use openembedded-core plus whatever layers you need.